# google places api quota, is it per user of app or per app in general?

Tags: google-places-api, google-oauth

I wanted to know if the free quota available for google places api is per user of the app or per app as a whole (entire user base)?

if this seems silly i'm sorry. please don't mark me down. i am a first time developer.

Answer (score 2):

From here: https://developers.google.com/places/usage

Applications that submit requests with an API key are allowed 1 000 requests per 24 hour period.

This would suggest it is per app as a whole.

Comment: I desperately need to use google's places database for my app and the app's user base as a whole would easily reach more than a 1000 request a day. Apple maps is no good for atleast india as its a shame for it cannot search places atleast in india, which google can. What do i do?

Comment: i switched to foursquare.